# How do you get a dynamic id with getElementById in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get a dynamic value in the document.getElementById in Javascript.

However, when I put a variable it does not work, like so:

```
var = myVar;
myVar = 'test';

document.getElementById(myVar);
```

How can I implement this?

Many thanks

Comment: That should work, if you have a single element with the id `test` in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work properly if you do it after the element has rendered, either by adding it in a callback on window.load, DOM ready, or put the script after the element in the HTML.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var el = 'bla'; document.getElementById(el).style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your syntax is wrong.

This:

```
var = myVar;
```

should be:

```
var myVar;
```

So you'd have:

```
var myVar;
myVar = 'test';

document.getElementById(myVar);
```

Then you can place the code in an `onload` to make sure the element is available.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kARDy/

```
window.onload = function() {

    var myVar;
    myVar = 'test';

    var element = document.getElementById(myVar);

    alert(element.innerHTML);
};
```

Comment: it's working perfectly fine but when I am getting variable from `Map` object and getting the `element` by `id` from it it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Were you supposed to have that equals? It should be:

```
var myVar = 'test';
document.getElementById(myVar);
```