# How to get checked property's value from passed control id in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have this JS script:

```
<script>
function getCheckedProperty(obj,args)
{
if(document.getElementById("<%=checkbox1.ClientID %>").checked)
return true;
else
return false;
}
</script>
```

This only works for checkBox1. I want to be able to pass control id from parameters, so that it can return value of passed control. Also, please, respond with the usage.

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="getCheckedProperty()></asp:CustomValidator>
```

TIY. SRJ.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934366/how-do-you-get-a-dynamic-id-with-getelementbyid-in-javascript) it might have your answer.

if I get it right you want to get ids dynamically for example checkbox1, checkbox2,...

You can add the dynamic part to the id like this:

```
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        var id = "checkbox" + i;
        var ch = document.getElementById(id);
        if (ch.checked == false)
             return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortantly, this is a real problem. The control name(s) are generated at runtime, and ALSO THIS:

```
document.getElementById("<%=checkbox1.ClientID %>")
```

So at page render time, the .net pre-processor will SWAP out the <% %> at render time.

this is also why you can't say have the js code in a external library and expect this to work.

However, your DEAD OBVIOUS question remains. Stuff a name into a simple variable and use that to get the control. After all, we can't and would not want to HARD code the value as per above, and it would be beyond silly to assume we ONLY have a means to HARD code references to controls.

So, you want of course this:

```
  var MyControl = 'Checkbox1';

  var ckBox = document.getElementById(MyControl);

   if (ckBox.checked) 
        alert('Check box ' + MyControl + ' is checked!');
   else
      alert('Check box ' + MyControl + ' is UN-checked');
```

Now in fact the ABOVE can and will work if you force the control name generation as static.

so, here is the markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

So, if you ARE able and ARE willing to use ClientIDMode static, then the .net processing will NOT re-name your control. As a result you can do this:

```
   var MyControl = 'Checkbox1';

   var ckBox = document.getElementById(MyControl);
```

Or, even this (as HARD coded)

```
   var ckBox = document.getElementById('CheckBox1');
```

Or even this:

```
   var ckbox2 = document.getElementById(<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>);
```

Now, the last one above? Well, we ARE useing the .net pre-processor to swap out the name - but it will still work - and clientID will not be changed - but the pre-processor is STILL involved.

AGAIN: the <%= 'SomeControlName.ClientID%> ONLY works because this expression is SWAPPED out at runtime by the .net web page pre-processor. This occures BEFORE the js code is run.

So you can NOT use a variable in the above <%=%> expressions since the js code HAS NOT even run and the new js code has not even been generated at this point in time.

In effect, you would (have to) do a PAGE search for the control. If you can NOT adopt ClientIdMode="static", then you MUST SEARCH the page.

You can write your OWN search routines - kind of like adopting a nice road to world poverty, or you bite the bullet, and adopt a library that WILL do the heavy lifting for you.

So, without using (forcing) StaticID on the control? then you now have to accept the BIG HUGE LARGE MASSIVE decision and introduce jQuery into your application.

jQuery is able to scour and search and look and loop and find that control for you on the web page. This is a cost not without processing cost, and not without a big speed penalty.

So, without staticID's, then you can adopt jquery and do this:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

 <script>

  // so if you decide and adopt jQuery, then it can do the searching for you
 // BUT YOU ARE now adopting and committing to a whole new js library

 // so, with jQuery we cna do this:
 

function jstest2(){

    var ckbox2 = $('#CheckBox1');
    var ckboxdom = ckbox2[0];
    alert('status of check box = ' + ckboxdom.checked);

    // of course the above is STILL hard code

    // get control by runtime or NON hard code
    // get (search) for check box based on control name in 
    // a variable

    var MyCheckBox = 'CheckBox1';
    var ckbox3 = $('#' + MyCheckBox);
    var ckboxdom3 = ckbox3[0];
    alert('status of check box = ' + ckboxdom3.checked);

    </script>
```

I found after doing a nuget of jQuery, the fans on my laptop became too hot to even keep on my lap. But, things did settle down, and eventually the VS editors caught up, and things did settle down.

Also keep in mind that you have to re-learn how to reference a simple control.

eg:

```
  <script>
   function getbox() {
      var tbox = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
      alert(tbox.value);

      // jQuery example
      var tbox2 = $('#TextBox1');
      alert(tbox2.val());
}
</script>
```

So notice now, how the long time js standard and approach is "value" as a property?

Well, now you using .val() that is a function (method) of that search result. So just keep in mind that by adopting jQuery, then all of your code that needs to get simple values from controls has to under go a syntax change, and you as a developer will have to re-lean how to reference a simple control with new syntax. The check box is a great example - it now becomes a array, and you use that array to get at the checked property.

And same in above for a simple grab of a value from a text box.
Notice how the syntax and approach to getting the value of the text box NOW has changed!!!! So you need a cheat-sheet since simple things like value now become .val().

And the same changes occur for say a label on a web page (again syntax changes).

You will ALSO notice that the results of the check box example are an array!!! So we had to drill down into the resulting array[] to get the "checked" value.

Of course how big of a deal your code changes are by adopting jQuery? Well, it depends, on relative medium sized or even a small project? $20,000 was budgeted and we still changing things.

On larger projects you simply need more manpower and would add another zero to the above cost to adopt jQuery.

However, jQuery is now widespread used, and it will do the "dirty work" of searching the DOM for you, and if you need runtime resolution as opposed to compile time resolution to find a simple control on a web page, then jQuery is probably your best choice. And I find that jQuery is really nice for ajax calls - so while it is a big change, it still well worth the effort to adopt the jQuery library and risk introducing this framework into your existing projects.